# Binomial and Beta-binomial regression error metrics

Tags: generalized-linear-model, predictive-models, error

I have dose-response data where my response is made up of successes and failures (i.e. binomially distributed) with a range of dose values. Typically the relationship between the two is positively related with a sigmoidal shape. The goal of my data is to make accurate predictions of the dose required to achieve a certain number of successes. Here is an example of some of my data.

```
    df <- structure(list(Dose = c(20, 14, 14, 20, 0, 0, 14, 14, 14, 16, 
10, 20, 20, 20, 16, 10, 10, 0, 16, 16, 16, 10, 0, 12, 10, 12, 
12, 0, 0, 20, 12, 16, 10, 12, 12, 0, 14, 14, 16, 0, 14, 20, 16, 
20, 14, 12, 12, 20, 20, 0, 0, 14, 12, 10, 10, 20, 16, 16, 14, 
10, 10, 10, 20, 16, 10, 0, 12, 12, 0, 12, 16, 14, 16, 14, 0, 
0, 12, 20, 0, 12, 14, 14, 0, 0, 20, 20, 20, 14, 14, 10, 10, 20, 
16, 16, 0, 12, 10, 10, 10, 16, 16, 12, 20, 10, 12, 12, 16, 14, 
0, 16, 20, 12, 14, 10, 10, 0, 0, 12, 12, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 14, 
12, 12, 20, 20, 14, 14, 14, 12, 20, 20, 20, 16, 16, 14, 10, 10, 
16, 16, 16), Success = c(100, 91, 87, 100, 0, 0, 91, 96, 89, 
96, 82, 99, 99, 99, 92, 59, 45, 0, 100, 95, 100, 83, 8, 82, 63, 
98, 74, 9, 0, 99, 78, 98, 53, 96, 52, 0, 62, 85, 98, 4, 89, 99, 
99, 97, 82, 80, 91, 99, 96, 0, 0, 95, 80, 68, 74, 100, 97, 93, 
87, 34, 32, 47, 99, 96, 86, 15, 93, 86, 0, 77, 89, 80, 98, 96, 
31, 0, 61, 100, 0, 84, 88, 97, 0, 0, 99, 100, 100, 92, 88, 46, 
51, 99, 97, 100, 0, 93, 61, 91, 57, 76, 95, 50, 98, 16, 87, 93, 
87, 88, 11, 92, 98, 60, 96, 0, 64, 72, 0, 74, 77, 0, 62, 0, 0, 
0, 84, 47, 69, 98, 100, 61, 90, 79, 11, 100, 98, 100, 98, 93, 
91, 58, 58, 93, 78, 69), Failure = c(0, 9, 13, 0, 100, 100, 9, 
4, 11, 4, 18, 1, 1, 1, 8, 41, 55, 100, 0, 5, 0, 17, 92, 18, 37, 
2, 26, 91, 100, 1, 22, 2, 47, 4, 48, 100, 38, 15, 2, 96, 11, 
1, 1, 3, 18, 20, 9, 1, 4, 100, 100, 5, 20, 32, 26, 0, 3, 7, 13, 
66, 68, 53, 1, 4, 14, 85, 7, 14, 100, 23, 11, 20, 2, 4, 69, 100, 
39, 0, 100, 16, 12, 3, 100, 100, 1, 0, 0, 8, 12, 54, 49, 1, 3, 
0, 100, 7, 39, 9, 43, 24, 5, 50, 2, 84, 13, 7, 13, 12, 89, 8, 
2, 40, 4, 100, 36, 28, 100, 26, 23, 100, 38, 100, 100, 100, 16, 
53, 31, 2, 0, 39, 10, 21, 89, 0, 2, 0, 2, 7, 9, 42, 42, 7, 22, 
31)), class = "data.frame", row.names = 433:576)
```

The models that I have been fitting are of the form:

`fit <- glm(cbind(Success, Failure) ~ Dose, weights = 100, family = binomial, data = df)`

I have been told that metrics like RMSE, MAE, etc., which are calculated through cross-validation, are not appropriate for this. I don't quite understand why, so my question is two part...

**Questions:**

1) Why is RMSE, MAE, etc. inappropriate for binomial data?

2) If they are inappropriate, is there a prediction error metric that can be used to compare different models which have a binomial distributed response?

Comment: You may want an approach like This: Pinheiro, J., Bornkamp, B., Glimm, E., & Bretz, F. (2014). Model‐based dose finding under model uncertainty using general parametric models. Statistics in medicine, 33(10), 1646-1661.